# Why was the TARDIS's broken slab left in the crack?

Tags: doctor-who

The Doctor grabbed the broken slab of the TARDIS as he put his hand into the crack. Why did this broken piece come into the hands of the Doctor? Is that a piece of TARDİS coming from future ?

(0.30-0.50 in video)

Comment: I'm pretty  sure I understood it.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

He examines the crack and finds a fragment of broken TARDIS inside.

This indicates that the cracks in time were going to be caused by the destruction of the TARDIS.

The destruction will happen in the Doctor's future, but the cracks appear throughout time, and so are seen in the past.

Comment: Yeah this is what I am asking thank you.